# Linear Transformation - proof isomorphism

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, vector-space-isomorphism

Hello I have the following question :

$W,V$ linear spaces with finite dimension above the same field.

$$T : V \rightarrow W$$ T is a linear transformation, let $U$ span of $V$ that impiles $V=U \oplus kerT$

$$S:U \rightarrow ImT$$

S is a linear transformation that is defined by $S(u)=T(u)$ for all $ u\in U $

Proof linear transformation $S$ isomorphism.

This is what I managed to get, I'm not so sure that I went in the right direction with this proof.

EDIT :

We know that : $$dimV=dimU+dimKerT$$ And as well that $$dimV=dimImT+dimKerT$$

Therefore we can conclude that $dimU=dimImT$

Any Idea how to process from this?

Thank you!

Comment: You're idea for a proof is wrong unfortunately: There is not reason why the kernel of $T$ should be zero.

Comment: @astudent I tried different idea, I think that could help me inorder to proof that S isomorphism. but not sure how, any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof is excellent so far!  You have $S:U \rightarrow \operatorname{Im}T$ is a linear transformation with $\dim(U) = \dim(\operatorname{Im}T)$.

In order to prove that $S$ is an isomorphism, it now is sufficient to show that $\ker(S) = \{0\}$.  However, we know that this is true since $V = U \oplus \ker T$, which by definition implies that $U \cap \ker T = \{0\}$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, just to make sure how you managed to reach to $KerS=\{0\}$ from $U \cap \ker T = \{0\}$ $$$$ we know that $KerS=KerT$ since $S(u)=T(u)$ for all $u \in U$ and as well we know that $ kerS \subseteq U$ therefore $kerS \cap U = \{0\}$ implies that $kerS=\{0\}$

Comment: Yes, that's a reasonable way to put it

Comment: More concisely: $\ker S \subseteq \ker T$ and $\ker S \subseteq U$ implies that $\ker S \subseteq U\cap\ker T = \{0\}$. So, $\ker S=\{0\}$.

Comment: All clear, thank you very much!

Comment: I'm doing the same question again and looking at it again, I think that the conclusion $\ker S \subseteq \ker T$ is wrong, I can understand that $ker S=ker T$ since we know that for all $u \in U \rightarrow S(u)=T(u)$ but since  $\ker S \subseteq U$ and also $U \cap ker T = \{0\}$ Therefore $ker S \cap ker T \{0\}$ I don't understand how you managed to get $ker S \subseteq ker T$ can you please explain?

Comment: We can say that $x \in V$ is in $\ker S$ if $x$ is in $U$ and $T x=0$. We can also say that an $x \in V$ is in $\ker T$ if $Tx=0$. So, if $x$ is in $\ker S$, then $x$ is also in $\ker T$.

Comment: It is **not** necessarily the case that $\ker S = \ker T$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer I really appreciate it.$$$$ I think I understand why the kernels could be not equal meaning $ker S \neq kerT$ since there might be $t \in kerT \implies T(t)=0$ and $t \not\in U \implies S(t) \neq 0$ Did I get it right? $$$$ Can you show a few more steps, I still can't understand why if $x \in U \rightarrow S(x)=0 \implies T(x)=0$ why for the same $x$ we chose $T(x)=0$?

Comment: Because if $x$ is such that $Sx$ is defined, $Sx=Tx$.

Comment: I'm sorry for so many questions it's just this material is really abstract, just last one question if I may, can you relate to the point of $kerS \neq kerT$ can you see what I written above or explain why it possible that $kerT \neq kerS$?

Comment: I thought it about it, can I say that $ker T \neq kerS$ because there could be $x \in V \rightarrow T(x)=0$ so that $x \not\in U$?

Comment: If you mean what I think you mean then yes, that's right.  We might have $U \subsetneq V$, and $T$ might have a non-trivial kernel.

Comment: Thank you (Toda Raba :) ). All clear now.